# Rewarded video ad is being failed to load

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

I have created an app with the rewarded video ad. When I click the button, the ad is not being loaded. I have tried testing the ad unit id and also my admob id, but neither work. Whenever I click the button, it shows " No fill from ad server. Failed to load ad: 3 "
I don't known what to do.

```
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(),"ca-app-pub-4786107620829013~6803627405");
    mad =   MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mad.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
    mad.loadAd("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx", new AdRequest.Builder().build());

public void Clicked(View view) {
    if (mad.isLoaded())
    {
        mad.show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Video loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Video Opened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Video Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {

     }

@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {

  }

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Complete Video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Have you added the testDevice?
You can see a log like -  Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("xxxx") to get test ads on this device.

Comment: I was Also tired that but its not work

Comment: When did you create the Ad in Admob? Sometimes, the Ad wont show if it was quite recently created in Admob.

Comment: I am also getting the same issue.